# Function calling error

Tags: javascript

Hey guys i am new to javascript app development ..i have did some javascript code but unfortunately it throws some error

The code which i have used is

```
var c = ( function() { this.name = function() { console.log('yay'); } }());
```

When i called the instance of the function c it throws error like `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Why cant i create the instance of function c ??...How can i call the function c so that i can call the inside function `name()`.

Thanx for your help..

Comment: in your case `c` is not a function, you need delete self execute, i mean `()` at the end of expresion

Answer (score 0):

Seems you've misunderstood the concept of IIFE. You would need `Object`

```
var c = {
    name: function() {
        console.log('yay');
    }
};
c.name(); // yay
```

But, if you need to go with `function`, then you would need a Constructor function, which would then be called with a `new` operator.

Comment: i want to use like (function() { this.name = function() { like that ..is it possible ? i dont want it as object

Comment: There are certain things, which you've to do to achieve what you want. AFAIK, that is not possible (`c.name()`)

Answer (score 0):

Use thisss

```
var c = function() { 
        this.name = function() {
            console.log('yay'); 
        } 
        };
newFunction=new c();

newFunction.name()
```

Comment: see i want to use like (function() { this.name = function() { like that ..is it possible ?

Comment: No if you use var it's not this

Answer (score 0):

Since, it is closure, you can not assign to variable `var c`. If you follow that pattern, you always have to enclose functions/operations inside that `(function() {} )`.

More on closure- http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/.

To use this, you can modify the js to like this.

```js
var c = (function() {
  var name;

  function setName(val) {
    name = val;
  }
  return {
    print: function() {
      setName("yay");
      console.log(name);
    }
  };
})();
console.log(c);
c.print();
```